# Publish mobile site on App Store and Google Play

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play

I have developed a responsive mobile version of a website like m.example.com. I was wondering if it is possible to upload the icon on Google Play and App Store which when downloaded by users opens the website in their mobile browsers.

If not, is there any other quick alternate way to have the mobile version of the website as an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://phonegap.com/

In the `config.xml` file, you can set the homepage of the app to be an external source.

Comment: I haven't actually ever used phonegap, if you can briefly explain how this would work I'd really appreciate it.